# The Jehovah’s Witnesses say Jesus created the angels, so why does Nehemiah 9:6 say God created them?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, creation, angels

They further say, "That is why the Bible calls Jesus "the firstborn of all creation by God, Read Colossians 1:15,16."

But at Nehemiah 9:6 it says, "Thou alone art the Lord, Thou hast made the heavens, The heavens of heavens with all their host, The earth and all that is on it, The seas and all that is in them. Thou dost give life to all of them **and the heavenly host bows down before Thee**." There is no "ambiguity" in this statement.

Moreover, Jehovah’s Witnesses teach, "Before he/Jesus was born in Bethlehem, Jesus lived as a spirit creature in heaven." They conclude that Michael is none other than Jesus Christ in his heavenly role.

Yet we have at Hebrews 1:6, "And when He again brings the first-born into the world, He says, "And let all the angels of God worship Him." The "Him" here is Jesus Christ. How do Jehovah’s Witnesses reconcile these clear discrepancies?

The "thrust" of my question mainly centers around Nehemiah 9:6. It clearly states the heavenly host/angles bows down and worships Thee/God, period. Since the Jehovah's Witnesses teach God created Jesus and then used him to make everything else, INCLUDING ANGELS and the Witnesses teach Jesus is Michael the arc angel how do they reconcile their teaching with Nehemiah 9:6?

Now, the second part of my question regarding Hebrews 1:6 is another contradiction from what the Witnesses teach and what Hebrews 1:6 is teaching. In this verse the Son is called "first-begotten" (prototokon). Paul said Christ was first begotten or "firstborn from the dead." Colossians 1:18. John wrote the same at (Revelation 1:5) Here "firstborn is an expression meaning Christ's resurrection from the dead.

Prototokon refers to either superiority in rank or first in time. Hebrews 1:5 spoke of Christ as the "begotten" in a quote from Psalm 2:7. the Father said to the Son, "This day have I begotten thee," but the statement refers not to a literal birth. Rather, it points to a position of rank. God later declared of the Messiah, "Also I will make him my firstborn, higher than the kings of the earth," Psalm 8927. here "firstborn" suggest being "supreme in rank" rather than "first in time."

In other words, God would make His Son as the Messiah higher than all other kings of the earth and even higher than the angels. This is also why the word for worship in the Greek is "proskuneo" and is used in this verse. It is also used at Luke 4:8 where Jesus said, "It is written, You shall worship the Lord your God and serve Him only." The word is "not" used in the sense of "obeisance" by expressing deep respect or deferential courtesy.

As a side note the founder of the Jehovah's Witnesses Charles Taze Russell taught that Jesus is not Michael the arc angel and He should be worshipped. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTgeE.jpg  Read it at about the middle of the page.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116788/discussion-on-question-by-mr-bond-the-jehovahs-witnesses-teach-god-created-jes).

Comment: Please [edit] this to ask an actual question in the question title box. This is not the first time you've written a statement in the question box. You also seem to be asking two basically entirely different questions here.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited what I posted in the form of a question. Thank You!

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed. JWS don’t say Jesus created the angels. There is only one creator, Jehovah.

Comment: @Kris Do you really think so Kris? https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20130301/when-jesus-created-why-son/  Please read the second paragraph. And I really hope you don't try and change the meaning.

Comment: Second paragraph states “God used Jesus to create everything else including the angels.”   God is still the creator.   An artist creates a paint brush then uses that brush to create countless works of art.  Are the works of art created by the artist or the brush?

Comment: You can read an explanation [here](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002451#h=7)

Comment: In addition  to the flawed premise of the question you are inserting prebuttals that detract from what should be a concise question.   What is a prebuttal?   An argument presented in anticipation of a critical response.

Comment: @Kris You little artist and paint brush syllogism won't work. Your first assuming God created Jesus. Secondly, Isaiah 44:24 says He created "All Alone" and By Himself" which would include the angels. Nehemiah 9:6 says the same thing. Thirdly, Isaiah 45:22 states, "For I am God and there is no other." You teach Jesus is "a god" and God says there are no other gods. Fourthly, what part of "By Himself" and "All alone" justifies using another created being to create so-called "other things," including the angels since you teach Jesus is also an angel named Michael?

Comment: Oh I see,   you don’t want to know what jws teach about anything. Instead you want to pontificate about why jws teachings are wrong.   That is fine but you will need to ask the question differently.       You could ask “according to the church of mr bond why are jws wrong in saying Jesus is not the creator but only an instrument used by Jehovah during the creative process.”